# TCP Client get unusual error

Tags: java, python, sockets, server, client

I wrote a socket client in Java and a server on python. I run a virtual machine (Ubuntu) in my desktop machine then start the server. If I run the client code on my notebook it works fine, I can send and receive data. The server closes but the problem is on my desktop computer. I copied the same code, but it doesn't work. It connects, and can send but doesn't receive. I figured it's a network problem but I haven't find a solution.

Here is my code

Python Server :

```
import socket 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("",9999)
s.listen(1)
sc,addr = s.accept()
recibido = sc.recv(4000000
print recibido
if (recibido == "Dante"): 
ed= "Im Cristian"
sc.sendall(ed)
```

Java client

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String str ="Dante";
        Socket s = new Socket ("192.168.1.104",9999);
        PrintStream p= new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.println(str);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String st = input.readLine();
        System.out.println(""+st);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(TCPCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }

}
```

Error on client

```
Error conecction reset
oct 08, 2017 2:18:15 PM tcpcliente.TCPCliente main
GRAVE: null
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at tcpcliente.TCPCliente.main(TCPCliente.java:26)
```

Could a firewall be the problem?

Comment: And when you searched for `tcp connection reset`, what did you find out? If you haven't tried that yet, then please do so.

Comment: sorry but i don't get the point what do you mean? when it shows the error part i just can cliock on the last line that is
 at `tcpcliente.TCPCliente.main(TCPCliente.java:26)`
and send me to the 26 line in my java client code 
`String st = input.readLine();`

Comment: The error is actually *unrelated* to your client code. It's a network problem, but most likely a problem on the other side of the connection, in the server. Have you checked what happens there? What I can see, the Python code you show is *invalid*, perhaps it stopped because of that?

Comment: yes, that's what i think because the client code  works on my notebook when i send it to my virtual machine in the desktop pc with the python server code  but the exact same client code doesn't work on my desktop pc

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was so silly that i feel like a clown, it seems that in my server i have "DANTE"  in Capital letters so it will never respond cause don't match with my client "Dante", sorry ppl.